# How could I found surrounding characters in select region in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, org-table

My question comes from I expect a function with could convert org-mode table to ditaa diagram. What I try to do is:

1. find "|" if there's any "-" at left/right/above/below, change it to "+"
2. find "+" if there's no "|" at left/right/above/below, change it to "-"

Can anyone show me how to search the character above/below or the entire function?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this to check what's on the next line:

```
(defun get-char-on-next-line (&optional point)
  "Return the character one line down from POINT.
If POINT is nil or omitted, use the current position of point."
  (save-excursion
    (when point
      (goto-char point))
    (let ((column (current-column))
          (line-move-visual nil))
      ;; next-line preserves the current column if possible
      (next-line)
      (when (= column (current-column))
        (char-after)))))
```

Replace `next` with `previous` for the opposite function.

Answer (score 0):

First, say thank you to @legoscia for the original solution.

When I try the (next-line)/(previous-line) I got some problems like "end of buffer, begin of buffer". Then I searched in elisp manual. It suggests using forward-line. Then I got my solution here:

```
(defun get-char-below (&optional point)
  "Return the character one line down from POINT.
If POINT is nil or omitted, use the current position of point."
  (save-excursion
    (when point
      (goto-char point))
    (let ((column (current-column)))
      (if (= (forward-line 1) 0)
          (if (= column (move-to-column column))
            (char-after)
          nil)
        nil))))
```